# Problem with JavaFX app origin being moved on load

Tags: javafx, fxml, scenebuilder

## Overview

We are currently working on a JavaFX app that will be loaded onto a Pi, the Pi is running Debian Linux.

We have an issue whereby when the app loads it appears that the origin of the application is being moved, something around -12px up over, and maybe -2px to the left.

We have added a splash screen to the application (Pink Rectangle with Green borders). This is also part of the same app. As you can see with the images below, when the splash loads up, it fits to the window perfectly (800x480), but then when the actual app screens come in they are being moved.

For reference, the FXML files are being styled etc in SceneBuilder.

Any help on this is appreciated!

---

## Setup as follows:

- Raspberry Pi model 3B+
- Touch Screen (7") - official Rasp Pi from OKDO - uses DSI not HDMI
- Debian (Build Buster)
- JavaFX (most recent version)
- SceneBuilder (...)
- NetBeans IDE (...)

---

## Images:

Here are a few images to show the problem:

[image: Image 1]
[image: Image 2]
[image: Image 3]

Comment: Can you explain your hardware setup more precisely?

Comment: you can edit the question to add details (vs. doing so in comments) which is a must to make it answerable, best in the form of a [mcve].

Comment: I was just puzzled by the "via an Android Touch Device". What has Android to do with this if it is running on a Pi?

Comment: Question updated, thanks for the tips (new here) :)

Answer (score 0):

This fixes it, although I suspect there's more to this.
The fix is applied when loading the scene ...

```
primaryStage.setScene(scene);

primaryStage.setX(0); // For some reason we absolutely need these. If we use 800x480
primaryStage.setY(0); // (ie. screen res) then we get a 2-pix border on right and 15 pix
primaryStage.setWidth(802) ; // border on bottom. !!!!!!!!!!!!! WTF !!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!
primaryStage.setHeight(509) ; // Setting the origin at 0,0 is also essential ! Work that out.

primaryStage.show();
```

Comment: glad you found a solution :) To make it readable, please format the code (each code line must start with 4 spaces - which can be achieved by selection and ctr-K)